# How magento count products which are imported one by one in DataFlow Process

Tags: magento

I am facing one issue! i am working on Import product Extension, I want to create same process functionality as Default Data Flow for import product does in Magento.I am nearer to the solution.

But I want to count product one by one same way the default Magento Import product Functionality does.

I am also attached one image here so that you can get an idea what i want is!

[image]

in above image you will get the idea what i want, i just want to count number of product which are imported one by one in magento.

so if you have any idea regarding this please let me know!

i am waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Each row that is to be imported is taken from dataflow_batch_import table from the database. So the number you want is the count of rows with the batch_id that correspond to your import.